# Creating a function that makes a 3D graph

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, graph

I am creating a function that when given two arrays of values, the function calculates a third array from these two and plots a graph of three variables. The arrays of values are essentially random.

What I have is: (where x and y are arrays of equal magnitude)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)


def f(x,y):
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)*np.pi
    t = g(x,y) #g(x,y) is a previously created function that takes one value of x 
               #and one of y and gives a number, hence this function should give
               #an array of numbers with the same index as x and y.
    c = np.array((x,y)) #just leaving this in case the surface requires a 2D array


    ax.scatter(???) #This is where I'm confused
return plt.show()
```

The thing is, I am a complete beginner, so when reading about how to create these surfaces and the arguments of the plots, I don't understand what to write. Also, I don't know what type of plot would be best to show the relationship between x, y, and t. I'm torn between wireframe plots, surface plots, tri-surface plots and scatter plots.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to take a look at this tutorial: http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html

It contains examples of all those plots you mentioned (with downloadable source).  The ultimate choice of which to use must be yours... totally subjective.

As an example, what you could write would be something like this (minimal working example)... in this case a 3d scatter plot.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x, y, t)
plt.show()
```

Comment: That's exactly the page I was looking for, but the arguments I'm writing, I don't know how to write them.

Comment: Do you mean that you do not understand how to use the functions (the tutorial is not clear in some way)?  If that's the case I can elaborate a little.

Comment: @George, You might want to double check and just print the t list (to make sure it is the list you intend).  I'm not certain how scoping works in python, but you might have to put the fig=plt.figure() etc all inside the def of the function (not certain on this but it may cause issues if you don't).